# Flutter app Error while initializing the Dart VM: Wrong full snapshot version, expected '8343.....' found '46b2....'

Tags: iphone, dart, flutter, xcode10

flutter app was working getting build and run on Xcode 10 on device iOS 12 fine before,

The time dart upgrade `2.1.0` happen in Flutter build iOS worked well with command and on Xcode 10 after build get success while running Flutter app on iPhone 7 iOS 12, it started giving error and app gets crash with following error message in Xcode logs.

> Error is Runner[410:28754] [VERBOSE-3:dart_vm.cc(403)] Error while initializing the Dart VM: Wrong full snapshot version, expected '8343f188ada07642f47c56e518f1307c' found '46b2bfb57b5647c5f7527ff9aa56c69b'

Here are the details of the flutter sdk and dart .

> Flutter 0.11.9 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
>   Framework • revision d48e6e4
>   Engine • revision 5c8147450d
>   Tools • Dart 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)

Comment: Try deleting `flutter/bin/cache` directory and then run `flutter doctor`

Comment: I did it , delete the cache directory , flutter clean , still it give the same error

Comment: Try `flutter clean`.

Comment: Try the different solutions proposed here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16103 
In my case, deleting the contents of `flutter/bin/cache` was the one working, as @GünterZöchbauer stated

Comment: I solved it by reinstalling the project no other way worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have experienced this error and none of the above solution worked for me infact the option of clearing the flutter/bin/cache messed the entire vscode IDE.
So I deleted the entire flutter SDK and installed fresh new SDK from flutter official website.
After this installation everything was working fine.

Comment: I had to do the same , only than it resolved, it was tough task had at one level thought to leave flutter

Answer (score 2):

Do `git clean -xffd` in flutter installed directory(repo).

If it's a Flutter project first try `flutter clean` if did not work, try above `git` command.

If still not solved, delete everything inside `/flutter/bin/cache` and try.

If still not :D,

Do `flutter channel master`, `flutter upgrade`, and `flutter clean`. If nothing worked please add a comment below.

If you are in Dart environment out flutter/bin/cach/dart-sdk, you may be not upgraded dart-sdk. This happen to me Dart 2.5.0 with chololate installed. So I just did `choco upgrade dart-sdk`

Comment: Among the other answers in this thread, including this git command worked for me. Here's the commands I used:
`git clean -xffd`
`flutter clean`
`flutter channel master`
`flutter upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue after a `flutter upgrade`. Uninstalling the app from the device and then `flutter run`ning it again solved the problem.

Comment: You are a genius. I have been struggling with this problem for several days, and all solutions involved manipulating the Flutter repository somehow, you were the first one that indicated that the problem could be on the device. I uninstalled the app and now everything works great. Too bad I can only vote once, thanks so much for this!

Answer (score 1):

After deleting the flutter/bin/cache and running `flutter clean`, I couldn't get the dart sdk to load until I launched the flutter console (flutter_console.bat) that can be found in the directory where you installed flutter and ran `flutter doctor` there. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly this problem i Solve it how ?
by these comments you just update flutter

`flutter channel beta`
,

`flutter upgrade`

you should upgrade your dart sdk

So try this command :

`choco install dart-sdk`

if this is not work for you  download it from this link
https://dart.dev/tools/sdk/archive;
and replace it with your current dart-sdk in flutter

Answer (score 1):

I also have experienced the same issue. I upgraded the flutter version and later downgraded and encounter this issue maily on IOS adhoc build.

Solution:
Delete out `$FLUTTER_HOME/bin/cache` and run flutter doctor.

This will solve.

Comment: After struggling with this issue for 2 days. Only this comment solved it for me

Comment: thanks a lot @prajeet Naga!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was changing channel and upgrading and then changing channel back and upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the flutter SDK folder in my computer completely and redownload the latest one at https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos

Then, I ran flutter doctor.

You can find where your flutter folder is by typing `which flutter` in your terminal.

Comment: I also had to do the same

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to uninstall the whole flutter and set environment path or anything else.

Just downgrade to any version by doing the below commands, suppose my current flutter version is **v3.3.8** and I come across this issue then:

1. Go to flutter sdk-path in the command prompt and checkout to any branch you would like to switch for a moment, like v2.5.0. So,
2. By doing this you changed your repository from v3.3.8 to v2.5.0

   ```
   git checkout v2.5.0
   ```

***You can check previous flutter versions from here***
[link](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases)

3. Downgrade your flutter version to 2.5.0

> `flutter downgrade v2.5.0`

4. Then upgrade flutter

> `flutter upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

My case: added flutter module as cocoapods, upgraded flutter but forgot to copy new Flutter.podspec.