# Wrong full snapshot version

Tags: flutter

> Wrong full snapshot version, expected 'b58ead73b2c5dfec69565df469bba387' found 'be7d304ff826e2dfac63538e227c3cc5'
> pub get failed (255; Wrong full snapshot version, expected 'b58ead73b2c5dfec69565df469bba387' found 'be7d304ff826e2dfac63538e227c3cc5')

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter app Error while initializing the Dart VM: Wrong full snapshot version, expected '8343.....' found '46b2....'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53431517/flutter-app-error-while-initializing-the-dart-vm-wrong-full-snapshot-version-e)

Answer (score 2):

Update the Flutter SDK with latest version.
By command: flutter upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove the flutter SDK folder completely and redownload the latest one.

Then run flutter doctor

https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos

Answer (score 0):

Clear flutter cache

rm -rf /flutter/bin/cache

then run  **flutter clean**.